# Should I keep drop down navigation menu open after the page loads?

Tags: dropdown, best-practice

I'm exploring the option of having the dropdown menu stay open when a user has clicked on going into that section.

Reasoning is that the client doesn't want to have a sub-menu when you're browsing this section [ its homepage and all the child to parent pages ] So unfort' the user has to go roll over the Header Navigation Link again to see what pages are found inside this section.

I'm trying to find other sites that may have done this to show the client, or should I be 100% trying to convince the client of going the route of having a sub-menu in the page [ as well as the on.Rollover hover drop down ] for UX best practices of providing easy to use navigation?

Any thoughts / feedback would be appreciated ;)

I've included this quick mockup of when a user is browsing inside the 'Funding' page

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points:

**Good design is design that meets users' expectations**

and

**Don't make users think (unnecessarily)**

Keeping a navigational element like this open after the page reloads is highly unconventional. It's likely to be perceived as an error or bug, and will result in distraction from the primary activity of scanning and understanding the page they have just landed on.

Explain the potential cost of deviating from convention, and provide examples of different types of submenus for him/her to choose from, because that is the logical design pattern for this scenario.